# Trigger to assign primary key number from sequence to be shared by multiple tables

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm on Oracle Database 18c Express Edition and APEX 19.1.

The requirement is to be able to link between items with same or different types:

1. logs with logs,
2. events with logs
3. ...and so on.

e.g.

**logs.item_id = 1**

- logs.item_id = 2
- events.item_id = 5

**logs.item_id = 2**

- logs.item_id = 1

**events.item_id = 5**

- logs.item_id = 1

---

My idea is to have a shared ID sequence, that would be populated with every insert on - for example - **logs** table.

Having unique IDs for **logs**, **events** and other items, I could create links in separate **links** table

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZDtb.png

---

After executing DDL script, my first

```
INSERT INTO events (dummy) VALUES ('D');
```

results with an error.

```
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (C##TEST.EVE_ITE_FK_1) violated - parent key not found
```

Following inserts assign sequence values starting from 3.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmihP.png

```
DROP TABLE items CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE logs CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE events CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE links CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP SEQUENCE items_seq;
DROP TRIGGER logs_trg;
DROP TRIGGER events_trg;
/
CREATE TABLE logs (
   item_id NUMBER(*,0) PRIMARY KEY
  ,dummy   CHAR(1));
/
CREATE TABLE events (
   item_id NUMBER (*,0) PRIMARY KEY
  ,dummy   CHAR(1));
/
CREATE TABLE links (
   id NUMBER(*,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
  ,item_id_1   NUMBER(*,0)
  ,item_id_2   NUMBER(*,0));
/
CREATE TABLE items (
   id NUMBER(*,0) PRIMARY KEY
  ,type CHAR(1 CHAR));
/
ALTER TABLE logs ADD CONSTRAINT log_ite_fk_1 FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES items (id);
/
ALTER TABLE events ADD CONSTRAINT eve_ite_fk_1 FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES items (id);
/
ALTER TABLE links ADD CONSTRAINT lin_ite_fk_1 FOREIGN KEY (item_id_1) REFERENCES items (id);
/
ALTER TABLE links ADD CONSTRAINT lin_ite_fk_2 FOREIGN KEY (item_id_2) REFERENCES items (id);
/
CREATE SEQUENCE items_seq START WITH 1;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER logs_trg FOR INSERT ON logs
COMPOUND TRIGGER
   l_item_id    PLS_INTEGER      := items_seq.nextval;
   co_item_type CONSTANT CHAR(1) := 'L';
BEFORE STATEMENT 
IS 
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO items(id
                    ,type) 
   VALUES (l_item_id
          ,co_item_type);
END BEFORE STATEMENT;
BEFORE EACH ROW 
IS 
BEGIN
   SELECT l_item_id
     INTO :NEW.item_id
     FROM dual;
END BEFORE EACH ROW;
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER events_trg FOR INSERT ON events
COMPOUND TRIGGER
   l_item_id    PLS_INTEGER      := items_seq.nextval;
   co_item_type CONSTANT CHAR(1) := 'E';
BEFORE STATEMENT 
IS 
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO items(id
                    ,type) 
   VALUES (l_item_id
          ,co_item_type);
END BEFORE STATEMENT;
BEFORE EACH ROW 
IS 
BEGIN
   SELECT l_item_id
     INTO :NEW.item_id
     FROM dual;
END BEFORE EACH ROW;
END;
/
```

Do you have any suggestions on what could I do to make it work with the 1st insert?

I expect

```
INSERT INTO events (dummy) VALUES ('D');
```

to produce items.id = 1 and events.item_id = 1.

---

**EDIT:**

Following Enrique's advice, I switched to non-compound trigger with `returning` clause - as below.

```
DROP TABLE items CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE logs CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE events CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE links CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP SEQUENCE items_seq;
/
CREATE TABLE logs (
   item_id NUMBER(*,0) PRIMARY KEY
  ,dummy   CHAR(1));
/
CREATE TABLE events (
   item_id NUMBER (*,0) PRIMARY KEY
  ,dummy   CHAR(1));
/
CREATE TABLE links (
   id NUMBER(*,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
  ,item_id_1   NUMBER(*,0)
  ,item_id_2   NUMBER(*,0));
/
CREATE TABLE items (
   id NUMBER(*,0) PRIMARY KEY
  ,type CHAR(1 CHAR));
/
ALTER TABLE logs ADD CONSTRAINT log_ite_fk_1 FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES items (id);
/
ALTER TABLE events ADD CONSTRAINT eve_ite_fk_1 FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES items (id);
/
ALTER TABLE links ADD CONSTRAINT lin_ite_fk_1 FOREIGN KEY (item_id_1) REFERENCES items (id);
/
ALTER TABLE links ADD CONSTRAINT lin_ite_fk_2 FOREIGN KEY (item_id_2) REFERENCES items (id);
/
CREATE SEQUENCE items_seq START WITH 1;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER logs_trg FOR INSERT ON logs
COMPOUND TRIGGER
   l_item_id    PLS_INTEGER      := items_seq.nextval;
   co_item_type CONSTANT CHAR(1) := 'L';
BEFORE STATEMENT 
IS 
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO items(id
                    ,type) 
   VALUES (l_item_id
          ,co_item_type);
END BEFORE STATEMENT;
BEFORE EACH ROW 
IS 
BEGIN
   SELECT l_item_id
     INTO :NEW.item_id
     FROM dual;
END BEFORE EACH ROW;
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER events_trg BEFORE INSERT ON events
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   co_item_type CONSTANT CHAR(1) := 'M';
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO items(id
                    ,type) 
       VALUES (items_seq.nextval
              ,co_item_type)
   RETURNING id INTO :NEW.item_id; 
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(systimestamp);
END;
/
INSERT INTO events (dummy) values ('D');
INSERT INTO events (dummy) values ('D');
```

Now the problem is different. The 1st insert on `events` table generates 2 values on `items_seq`

```
INSERT INTO events (dummy) VALUES ('D');

DBMS_OUTPUT:
08-MAY-19 11.08.29.301000000 +02:00
08-MAY-19 11.08.29.303000000 +02:00
```

Ongoing inserts behave as expected - 1 seq number for each insert. So 2 inserts generate 3 sequence values.

My desired outcome is to have `items.id` = 1 for first insert on `events` table.

Comment: Could you put the error message in the question, instead of linking to an image that only shows half of it?

Comment: Why `items.id` is `generated always as identity`? Your triggers put there values from sequence. When I run (partial) script without that clause I had no errors.

Comment: @PonderStibbons You're right. My mistake. I've set it to ```primary key``` only. 
@GolezTrol Good point! Done.

Comment: Due to database normalization, you could also consider creating another table that has its primary key filled by an identity. Then, your other tables can use that as their foreign key. Need for trigger eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

v_myid number;

insert into table(col1, col2)
    values(value1, value2)
    returning id into v_myid;

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I adjusted the code, but trigger still behaves not exactly as I'd expect it to. Please see edited content in the original post.